# How to Use the Stack class in the

Tags: java, stack

I have a Parameter class which just has parameters

```
Parameter
{

 String inputfilename;
 int numA;
 double numbB;
  etc...
}
```

and ProcessParameter class that has methods defined

```
ProcessParameter
{
  openParameters
  {

     //Open file and read the parameters into the Parameter object
     BufferedReader openFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(parameterFileName));
     String[] tokens = openFile.readLine().trim().split(DELIMITER); 
     Parameter openparameter = new Parameter();     
     openParameter.setInputFileName(tokens[0]);

     openFile.readLine();
     openParameter.setNumA = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);

}
```

**My Question is : How do I use stack directly on the Parameter Class?** **( i have about 15 parameters in the parameter class and will be using Update, save and open methods in the ProcessParameter class)**

I was trying:

```
     Stack<Parameter> stack = new Stack<Parameter>();
     stack.push(tokens[0]);

     openFile.readLine();
     **stack.push(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]));**
```

I get this warning: 
**The method push(Parameter) in the type Stack is not applicable for the arguments (int)**
Would really appreciate any pointers and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to push an `int` when you said the Stack should contain `Parameter` instances.

You'll either need to change the generic type of `stack` or change how you store your `tokens`.